Why my selected item from list view isn't working?
WPF:
<ListView x:Name="ToursListView" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredTours}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTour}" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FF4282EB" BorderThickness="2" Margin="20" Width="300">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Helvetica" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateToTourDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=YourListView}" Style="{StaticResource NoFocusCueButton}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                        <Button.Cursor>
                            <Cursor>Hand</Cursor>
                        </Button.Cursor>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePaths, Converter={StaticResource FirstImageConverter}}" Margin="30,5,30,5" Height="150"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="Reserve" Click="TourDetailsClick" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

C#:
private Tour _selectedTour;
public Tour SelectedTour
{
    get { return _selectedTour; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedTour != value)
        {
            _selectedTour = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTour));
        }
    }
}

This is code in viewModel (dataContext is set on this model)
In ListView in wpf I have this line -- ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredTours}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTour}"
FilteredTours work perfectly fine, I can see all the tours that I need, but SelectedTour allways returns null.
I debugged the code and when I click on any element from list, the program does not reach the set method as it should.
Also viewModel extends this class:
 public class TouristViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     [field: NonSerialized]
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
 }


It should work when you click on the Tour Name text. Other click events are swallowed by the Buttons in the ItemTemplate.
